# How to handle parallel requests to different URLs on Citrus server?

Tags: concurrency, mocking, citrus-framework

I'm doing integration testing for a couple microservices with the [Citrus framework](http://citrusframework.org/). The test setup is roughly this:

1. Send a request from a Citrus HTTP client to one of the microservices
2. Several microservices send requests to the same remote host (which I want to mock away with a Citrus HTTP server) concurrently, calling different URLs on that remote host (e.g. "http://server.com/A/" and "http://server.com/Z/E/F/") or the same URL with different query parameters (e.g. "http://server.com/A?param=1" and "http://server.com/A?param=great")
3. The Citrus server should return different responses dynamically calculated from the specific URL call that it's responding to
4. All subsequent verification steps require no interaction with the Citrus server.

I can't figure out how to set this up such that the test is not vulnerable to race conditions. I've tried the variations on the solutions suggested in [this github thread](https://github.com/citrusframework/citrus/issues/550) that I could think of, but can't figure out how to adjust it to my use case. I'm trying to put the different request-response pairs into separate [async()](http://citrusframework.org/citrus/reference/html/index.html#containers-async)-containers, but the responses end up getting switched under the wrong race conditions and my tests fail frequently. I try to mock each request-response-pair like this:

```
private void serverReceiveCallAndRespond(String path, Resource response) {
    async().actions(
        http().server(citrusHttpServer)
            .receive()
            .get(path),
        http().server(citrusHttpServer)
            .send()
            .response(HttpStatus.OK)
            .contentType("application/json")
            .messageType(JSON)
            .payload(response)
    );
}
```

TLDR: how can I tell a Citrus server to respond to calls to different URLs with different responses asynchronously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use `message selectors` to solve this. The Citrus server pushes all incoming requests to an internal message channel. You can pick a message explicitly form that channel using message selectors.

```java
http().server(citrusHttpServer)
            .receive()
            .get(path)
            .selector(Collections.singletonMap(HttpMessageHeader.HTTP_REQUEST_URI, "/Z/E/F/"))
```

This way you can always receive the request on `/Z/E/F/` first in your test and respond to that with proper response. After that you can add a 2nd receive using another selector and provide a proper response to that call.

The sequence of incoming requests is then not bound to racing conditions anymore.

Not sure about the `HttpMessageHeader.HTTP_REQUEST_URI` header though. You might need to use the complete request URI here as value.

Comment: This worked without any changes necessary to the code you provided, thanks!